# Obtener de X fichero, el archivo mas reciente!

Tags: java

me podrían ayudar mira tengo el siguiente problema.

Me piden buscar de X dirección (\nn.nn.n.nnn\RutaArchivos\Archivox\Inbox) el archivo con la fecha mas reciente y poder leer dicho archivo.

Bueno eso de leerlo no es problema el, problema que tengo es como saber de esa ruta, saber cual es el archivo mas reciente!

Agradeceria su ayuda gracias!

Comment: Agrega el código de como obtienes esa ruta por favor, revisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389225/android-how-to-get-a-files-creation-date/2390177#2390177

Answer (score -1):

Primero debes listar todos los archivos que contiene el directorio (según la ruta dada) con el método y luego puedes utilizar el método [File#lastModified()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#lastModified()), que te permite obtener la fecha de la última modificación de un archivo (en milisegundo), ir comparando hasta encontrar el último. También puedes apoyarte, como indican en la documentación del método anterior, de [Files#readAttributes(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Class,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) con el que puedes obtener mucha más información del archivo.

Comment: si algo he leido del lastModified(), mira te dejo mi ejemplo:

Comment: FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
                    return fileName.endsWith("txt");
                }
            };

            File carpeta = new File("\\\\xx.x.xxx.xx\\Compartido\\");
            File[] archivos = carpeta.listFiles();

Comment: archivos = carpeta.listFiles(filter);

            if (archivos == null || archivos.length == 0) {
                System.out.println("No hay elementos dentro de la carpeta actual");
                return;
            } else {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                for (int i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {
                    File archivo = archivos[i];
                    System.out.println(archivo.getName() + " " + sdf.format(archivo.lastModified()));
                }
            }

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega tu ejemplo ahí, para que esté más completa.